# PHP associative array can't add new elements

Tags: php, html, associative-array

I'm learning PHP and as exercise I'm trying to create a very simple webpage where I can select some fruits from a list, select the quantity and then add them to a cart where it will be displayed the name of the fruit, the total cost for its quantity and the final purchase cost.
For the cart I initialised an empty associative array, and when clicking on "add to cart" the code will add the new fruit (name of fruit it's the key, the product of its price and quantity will be the value).

I already looked around but every solution result in having the cart with only one item since it will be overwritten by the next one.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
    <body>
    <?php
    $qty = $price = 0;
    $sel = '';
    $cart = array();
    $fruits = array("Apple"=>1.4,"Banana"=>1.7,"Chestnuts"=>4,"Kiwi"=>1,"Mandarins"=>1.75,"Mango"=>1.99,"Pear"=>4,
        "Pineapple"=>1.5,"Pomegranate"=>1.5,"Rambutan"=>30,"Red dragon"=>8);

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if ($qty==0) {
            $qty = $_POST["qty"];
        }
        if (($price==0) && empty($sel)) {
            $price = $fruits[$_POST["fruit_list"]];
            $sel = $_POST["fruit_list"];
        }
    }

    function price($price,$qty) {
        return $price*$qty;
    }
    ?>

    <h1> Welcome to Edeka, here's your options: </h1>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <div>
            <label for="fruit_list">Available fruits:</label>
            <select name="fruit_list" id="fruit_list">
                <option value="">--- Choose a fruit ---</option>
                <?php
                    // Iterating through the product array
                    foreach($fruits as $x => $x_value){
                        echo "<option value=$x>$x $x_value €</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div>
            <label for="qty">Kilos of fruit to take (0.1 - 10):</label>
            <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" min="0.1" max="10" step="0.1">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart">
        <?php
            echo "<h2>Your cart:</h2>";
            echo "<br>";

            if (!empty($sel)){
                $cart[$sel] = price($price,$qty);
            }

            if (!empty($sel)) {
                foreach ($cart as $x => $x_value) {
                    echo $x . " -> " . $x_value ."€";
                }

            }
        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help

Comment: Every time you submit that form, whatever variables you have are lost unless you use some sort of persistent storage such as session variables or store the cart in a database.

Comment: PHP has no "memory". As soon as the script is finished, all data is wiped clean. So `$cart` will always be empty when the script is receiving a POST, hence if you add an item there always will be only one item. If you want to "remember" data in PHP, you have tot store it. There are several options: use a file, a database or use a  [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Websites are inherently stateless.  To carry information from one page to another you need to use the session or cookies.